# Why Pi Camera rounds up resolution to the nearest 16 multiple

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, resolution

I am interested in reading the raw data from a Raspberry Pi Camera V1.3 and V2.1. I reached a point where the Picamera module documentation provided a very helpful code to extract the data.

However, why does sensor originally round up originally the resolution to nearest multiple of 16. I quote the docs, full code [here](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#raw-bayer-data-captures):

```
# For the V1 module, the data consists of 1952 rows of 3264 bytes of data.
# The last 8 rows of data are unused (they only exist because the maximum
# resolution of 1944 rows is rounded up to the nearest 16).
#
# For the V2 module, the data consists of 2480 rows of 4128 bytes of data.
# There's actually 2464 rows of data, but the sensor's raw size is 2466
# rows, rounded up to the nearest multiple of 16: 2480.
#
# Likewise, the last few bytes of each row are unused (why?). Here we
# reshape the data and strip off the unused bytes.

reshape, crop = {
    1: ((1952, 3264), (1944, 3240)),
    2: ((2480, 4128), (2464, 4100)),
    }[ver]
data = data.reshape(reshape)[:crop[0], :crop[1]]
```

Many Thanks.